# From Odoo 8, access to data of an OpenERP object in another database

Tags: python, orm, odoo-8, openerp-7

We have an OpenERP 7 instance and I am working with an Odoo 8 instance. The two instances are separately working, but I want to do an Odoo module to be able to connect to an specific table/object in OpenERP and retrieve data when it is needed. It is like a migration, but it won't be the only time it has to be executed, therefore, it has to be an executable code.

Is it possible? Could you give me an example code about the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with sql you could create a connection to the database on a separate cursor object and execute queries. You can use the python library [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/)

There are a few odoo client libraries such as [erppeek](https://erppeek.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which can be used to interact with odoo via a python environment. So it might be ideal. You can create a connection to your other OpenERP instance by creating a erppeek client object and then you can query the db using a syntax that is rather similar to native odoo. Here is an example.

```
import erppeek
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

password = "your_password"
server = "http://localhost:8069"
user = "your_user"
db = "your_db"

Client = erppeek.Client(server,db,user,password)
if Client:
    Client.login(user,password)
    partners = Client.browse([])
    for partner in partners:
        _logger.info("FOUND PARTNER: {}".format(partner.name))
```

Now you have access to the records and can do whatever you wish with them on your odoo instance.

There is also xmlrpc which is what is used in the erppeek library. Documentation on xmlrpc/jsonrpc can be found on Odoo's website.